# Find all unique longest paths with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is unrelated to [how to find all the longest paths with cypher query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764527/how-to-find-all-the-longest-paths-with-cypher-query), and somewhat related to the answer in [Find all relationship disjoint longest paths in cypher/traversal API ordered by size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108106/find-all-relationship-disjoint-longest-paths-in-cypher-traversal-api-ordered-by/30110495#30110495) except my condition is a bit different:

I would like to write a cypher query that returns paths whose collections of nodes are "unique", in the sense that no two nodes in the path share the same `name` property.

Here's an example graph:
[image]

and the cypher to make it:

```
CREATE (a1:Node {name: 'A', time:1}),
(c1:Node {name: 'C', time:2}),
(b1:Node {name: 'B', time:3}),
(d1:Node {name: 'D', time:4}),
(c2:Node {name: 'C', time:5}),
(a2:Node {name: 'A', time:6}),
(a3:Node {name: 'A', time:7}),
(b2:Node {name: 'B', time:8}),
(d2:Node {name: 'D', time:9})

CREATE (a1)-[:NEXT]->(b1)-[:NEXT]->(c2)-[:NEXT]->(a2)-[:NEXT]->(b2),
(a2)-[:NEXT]->(a3)-[:NEXT]->(d2),
(c1)-[:NEXT]->(b1),
(d1)-[:NEXT]->(c2)

RETURN *
```

In this graph, the following paths are considered longest, and unique:

```
(a1)-->(b1)-->(c2)
(c1)-->(b1)
(d1)-->(c2)-->(a2)-->(b2)
(a3)-->(d2)
```

Some example of paths that should not be returned from the query are

1. `(c1)-->(b1)-->(c2)` since it contains two instances of nodes with name, "C"
2. `(a2)-->(b2)` since it is contained in the larger path `(d1)-->(c2)-->(a2)-->(b2)`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
//
// Find all path:
MATCH path = (a:Node)-[:NEXT*1..]->(b:Node)
//
// Check that the names of the nodes in a path is unique
UNWIND nodes(path) as node
WITH path, nodes(path) as nodes, 
     collect(DISTINCT node.name) as unames
  //
  // And sort by path length
  ORDER BY length(path) ASC
  WHERE length(path)+1 = size(unames)
//
// Putting the appropriate path to the collection
WITH collect({f: id(HEAD(nodes)), // Fist node in path
              l: id(LAST(nodes)), // Last node in path
              ns: EXTRACT(n in nodes(path) | id(n)), 
              p: path
     }) + {f: NULL, l: NULL, ns: [NULL]} as paths
//
// Loop through the paths in a double loop 
// and check that the start and end nodes 
// are not included in the following ascending path
UNWIND RANGE(0,size(paths)-2) as i
  UNWIND RANGE(i+1,size(paths)-1) as j
    WITH i, paths, paths[i]['p'] as path, 
         sum( size( FILTER(n in paths[j]['ns'] WHERE n=paths[i]['f']) )) as fc, 
         sum( size( FILTER(n in paths[j]['ns'] WHERE n=paths[i]['l']) )) as fl
    WHERE fl=0 OR fc=0
//
// Return all appropriate ways
RETURN path ORDER BY length(path)
```

***Upd:*** (let's try to add elegance)

```
//
// Find all path:
MATCH path = (a:Node)-[:NEXT*1..]->(b:Node)
//
// Check that the names of the nodes in a path is unique
UNWIND nodes(path) as node
WITH a, b, path,
     collect(DISTINCT node.name) as unames
  //
  // And sort by path length
  ORDER BY length(path) ASC
  WHERE length(path)+1 = size(unames)
//
// Putting the appropriate path and first and last nodes to the collection
WITH collect({first: a, last: b, path: path}) + {} as paths
//
// Loop through the paths in a double loop 
// and check that the start and end nodes 
// are not included in the following ascending path
UNWIND RANGE(0,size(paths)-2) as i
  WITH i, paths[i]['path'] as path, paths
    UNWIND RANGE(i+1,size(paths)-1) as j
      WITH path,
           collect(distinct paths[i]['first'] IN nodes(paths[j]['path'])) as cFirst,
           collect(distinct paths[i]['last']  IN nodes(paths[j]['path'])) as cLast
        WHERE (size(cFirst)=1 AND cFirst[0] = false) OR
              (size(cLast )=1 AND cLast [0] = false)
//
// Return all appropriate ways
RETURN path ORDER BY length(path)
```

Comment: So, this seems to work (result when run on my sample graph: http://pastebin.com/jxeKkr1f): I'm just wondering if 1) this is "idiomatic cypher", and 2) if there's a way to make that massive `WITH collect(...) as paths` statement more readable (or elegant)? Also, why is the `collect(DISTINCT id(node)) as uids` necessary?

Comment: @StevieP 1) I think that is quite typical, although check nesting paths in each other, I would have already suffered at the application side. 2) See the update - it became better, imho :)) 3) `collect(DISTINCT id(node)) as uids` - need to check that the path does not intersect with itself - if you are sure that it can not be - take away this part.

Comment: You can definitely assume that the graph is a DAG, so self-intersection shouldn't be a problem (the relations are time-based). Regarding the application layer: if you could perform this task in python (for example) what would you leave to Cypher vs. Python?

Comment: If DAG - can safely remove this part. At the application layer, I would have moved the second part (two-cycle UNWINW) - testing for sub-path.

Comment: so, use Cypher for fast path retrieval and coarse filtering and then do the more imperative stuff in app? Also, what is UNWINW? (Sorry for the newbie questions!)

Comment: Yes. `UNWINW` - it is `UNWIND`. My typo, sorry :)